# Call dialog from another Class

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I got the following :

- A class called `DConce` which contains the code of one dialog I'm gonna use:

  ```
      public class DConce extends DialogFragment{

  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  AlertDialog.Builder dshow = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

  LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

  dshow.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogconc, null))

         .setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                 //TODO


             }
         })
         .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                 DConce.this.getDialog().cancel();
             }
         });      

  return dshow.create();

  }
  ```

and another class into a Fragment called `public final class Sincr extends Fragment` where I need to call the dialog on a :

```
 case R.id.btnConce:
    //here      
            break;
```

How would I do that?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to add to your code is newInstance like:

```
public static DConce newInstance(){
    DConce arg = new DConce();
    return arg;
  }
```

And then in activity:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager(); // or getFragmentManager, depends on which api lvl you are working on but supportFragmentManager will make you dialog work also on devices lower than api lvl 11(3.0 - > Honeycomb)
DialogFragment Dialog = DConce.newInstance();
Dialog.show(manager, "tag");
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify your DialogFragment:

```
public class DConce extends DialogFragment{

  public static DConce newInstance(){
    DConce f = new DConce();
    return f;
  }

  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dshow = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    dshow.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogconc, null))
      .setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
           //TODO
        }
      })
      .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
          DConce.this.getDialog().cancel();
        }
      });     
    return dshow.create();
  }    
}
```

Then to show it;

```
case R.id.btnConce:
  DConce.newInstance().show(getChildFragmentManager(), null);
  break;
```

You can of course optionally pass in a `String` for the `tag` parameter, to uniquely identify the fragment.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the android document here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Answer (score -1):

Create static method and put your code inside .

and call directly by class name i.e `Dcon.myAlertMessage()`